# print関数を記入してもXcode画面下部に表示されない

Tags: swift, xcode

先日print関数を記入したところ、Xcode画面下部に表示されないということが起こりました。
コードの問題はなく、swiftで、パスを設定した際に、保存場所を確かめるためにprintを使用したり、計算の結果を表示させるために使用していたのですが、なぜ急に表示されなくなってしまったのでしょうか？
原因がわかる方がいましたら、ご教授のほど、お願いいたします。

追記
「Activate Console」を選択したところ以下のようなものが出ており、printした部分のパスや数値は出てきませんでした。 AuthenticationSystem[16949:3264446] Unknown class _TtC20AuthenticationSystem14ViewController in Interface Builder file.

Answer (score 2):

コードに問題が無いという前提ですと、コンソールエリアが表示されていないということではないでしょうか。

それが原因でしたら、Xcodeで「View」メニューの「Debug Area」から「Activate Console」を選択して、コンソールエリアが表示してから、再度、「print」関数を実行したら表示されると思います。

Comment: 「Activate Console」を選択したところ以下のようなものが出ており、printした部分のパスや数値は出てきませんでした。
AuthenticationSystem[16949:3264446] Unknown class _TtC20AuthenticationSystem14ViewController in Interface Builder file.

Comment: 英語版のStack overflowで、次の様なポストを見つけました。これと同じ現象かもしれません。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file